# Keras Custom Layer calling fit method before compile

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow

Below is the SS of the custom function I am trying to apply on every image of the batch and the custom Layer

```
def geo_features( input_img ):
    print( "INPUT IMAGE SHAPE:", input_img.shape, type( input_img ) )
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor( config.SHAPE_PREDICTOR_DAT_PATH )
    cv2.imshow( 'test', input_img )
    cv2.waitKey( delay = 0 )
    img = cv2.resize(
        input_img,
       (
         config.TARGET_SIZE['CV2_LANDMARKS_RESIZE'][0],
         config.TARGET_SIZE['CV2_LANDMARKS_RESIZE'][1]
       )
    )
    row = [ ( -100, -100 ) ]
    faces = detector( img )
    .
    .
    .


class GeoFeatures( keras.layers.Layer ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super( GeoFeatures, self ).__init__()
        print( "BUILDING CUSTOM LAYERS")

    def call( self, inputs ):
        print( "INSIDE CALL METHOD" )
        return tf.map_fn( fn = tf.py_function( geo_features ), elems = inputs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return ( input_shape[0], config.NUM_GEOMETRIC_FEATURES )
```

The issue I am facing is, the `GeoFeatures` `call` method is being called before compilation as evident from the below pics:-
[image]

Below is part of the training code. (NOTE:- `model_dispatcher.return_mode()` is just returning the keras.Model and nothing else).

```
train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe = train_df,
            directory = None,
            x_col = "Image",
            y_col = "Label",
            target_size=(config.TARGET_SIZE[config.MODELS[num_fold-1]][0], config.TARGET_SIZE[config.MODELS[num_fold-1]][1]),
            class_mode = "categorical",
            shuffle = True,
            color_mode = config.COLOR_MODE[config.MODELS[num_fold-1]],
            batch_size = config.BATCH_SIZE,
            seed = 42
        )

        val_data = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe = val_df,
            directory = None,
            x_col = "Image",
            y_col = "Label",
            target_size=(config.TARGET_SIZE[config.MODELS[num_fold-1]][0], config.TARGET_SIZE[config.MODELS[num_fold-1]][1]),
            class_mode = "categorical",
            color_mode = config.COLOR_MODE[config.MODELS[num_fold-1]],
            shuffle = True,
            batch_size = config.BATCH_SIZE,
            seed = 42
        )

        print( train_data.class_indices )
        print( "DISPATCHING MODEL" )
        model = model_dispatcher.return_model( num_fold )
        mc, reduce_lr = return_callbacks(
            num_fold,
            isBest
        )
        print( "NOT YET COMPILED")
        opt = return_opt( 'adam', learning_rate = 1e-3 )
        model.compile(
            optimizer = opt,
            loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics = ['accuracy']
        )
        model.fit( .. )
        .
        . 
        .
        .
```

As can be seen clearly, the compilation is not yet done still the `call` method of layer is being called resulting in an error.

For more clarity below is the model which is incorporating the custom layer. Full model code is not shown as it is irrelevant as the custom layer is used only once here. At the last, the `customXceptionWithGeo` returns `Keras.Model( inputs, outputs )`

```
def customXceptionWithGeo( TARGET_SIZE ):
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(TARGET_SIZE)

    y = GeoFeatures()( inputs )
    y = Dense( 16, activation = 'relu' )( y )
    y = Dense( 32, activation = 'relu' )( y )
    y = Dropout( 0.4 )( y )
    y = Dense( 64, activation = 'relu' )( y )
    y = Dense( 32, activation = 'relu' )( y )
    y = Dense( config.NUM_CLASSES )( y )
    .
    .
    x = ...
    .
    .
    x = layers.add( [ x, y ] )
    outputs = Activation('softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    return keras.Model( inputs, outputs )
```

Comment: Instead of implementing all the logic of `geo_features()` method in a custom Keras `Layer`, I'd suggest you to create another `Input` layer for your model and pass the data to this input layer ( which is already processed by calling `geo_features()` method ).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I understand that that can be done. But, as you can see in customXceptionWithGeo model that, this geometric model's output is getting merged into another model( defined from x = ... ). Let's call this another model as "Main model" The take is, I am applying feature extraction on the augmented image( which is getting fed into the Main model ) for the geometric model and the same augmented image is getting fed into the main model too. At last, the outputs of both models are merged.